Can't publish a release build of Monogame project
When I attempt to package my Monogame project in release build, the exe it produces doesn't run.
I have tried using the publish window in Visual Studio and running the package command provided on the Monogame site:
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 /p:PublishReadyToRun=false /p:TieredCompilation=false --self-contained
I've even tried changing things like making it non self-contained and tweaking the other values, however if it's a release build, it doesn't run.
